# Calculating TAX in PHP and displaying correct decimals

Tags: php, decimal, rounding

I am trying to calculate the tax for my shopping cart, plus a service charge. For the most part I think I have it correct, however, when I try to output the Grand Total, if the number ends in a "0", it is left off. In other words, if the Grand Total happens to be $13.50, the total is actually displayed as $13.5

I am echoing out the info, but here is the code that I have tried. I am currently using ROUND already.

```
            $tax = .065;
            $service = .18;
            $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
            $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;
            $totalwithtax = round($cartTotal + ($cartTotal * $tax), 2); //Order Items + Tax
            $servicecharge = round($totalwithtax * $service, 2); //service charge       
            $grandtotal = round($totalwithtax + ($totalwithtax * $service), 2); //service charge
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use number_format() function :)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Ex:

```
echo number_format($grandtotal,2,'.','');
```

Comment: @user3150191 don't forgot to click to the green tick under the down arrow :)